# date different with php comparing returned date from DB and current date

Tags: php, sql-server

let say i have a date Jun 9 2008 12:00AM and want to calculate how many days from NOW.
can i do it using php ?

Note: The possible date can also be returned as 09/06/2008.

Try to use DATEDIFF frm http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx  but no luck..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tried the Microsoft SQL Server version of DATEDIFF, but your question is tagged as MySQL.

Try this one:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), yourDateColumn) FROM yourTable;
```

**UPDATE** (now that we know that it's actually MSSQL):

You need to clarify your question. What do you mean with "I have a date"? Is the date in the database? If yes, show the way you tried the DATEDIFF function. If it's a valid date in the database it doesn't matter how it is formatted and the following should definitely work:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(d, yourDateColumn, GETDATE()) FROM yourTable;
```

Is the column type maybe not date but varchar? Then you can convert it like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, yourDateColumnOrYourStringOrWhatever , format) ...
```

[Here you can see which formats you can use](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/).

Again, post more info or we can't help you. And I'm not going to guess around more.

Answer (score 0):

You should use mysql [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it in php, so:

```
round((strtotime('now')-strtotime('Jun 9 2008 12:00AM'))/3600/24)
```

but `DATEDIFF` is much better